# GET result was undefined/null in IE11, until a change was made to webpack file. Any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, webpack, get, internet-explorer-11

I'm making multiple GET requests within a project and all of them were fine in IE11 *except* for a particular call.

The error was something like: `Unable to get property X of undefined or null reference.` Expanding the error mentioned anonymous functions.

I readjusted my `webpack.test.js` file (I realized it had been changed) and I brought back a block of code. Doing this caused the request to run properly.

```js
module.exports = merge({
    entry: {
      '/SiteAssets/scripts/somefile': './src/index.js'
    }
  },
  common, {
   mode: 'production',
   devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // This line and the devServer block were brought back
   devServer: {
     contentBase: './dist',
     compress: true,
     historyApiFallback: false
   },                                      // 
   stats: {
      colors: false,
      hash: true,
      timings: true,
      assets: true,
      chunks: true,
      chunkModules: true,
      modules: true,
      children: true,
   }
  }
);
```

**Any ideas as to why this worked?** I've been trying to think of reasons why, but I haven't had any luck. I'm interested in finding out so I can avoid it in the future, if possible.

Comment: The `devtool` is related with source map and I think it's not the influence factor. And just a kind reminder: *pay attention and dont mix up the sequence of devtool string. The pattern is: `[inline-|hidden-|eval-][nosources-][cheap-[module-]]source-map`.* Maybe the `devServer` options have influence. `devServer.contentBase` tells the server where to serve content from and I think different values will have different results. You can try to change `devServer` options' values and see with which combination it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging with a more experienced dev, and although commenting out the code from the webpack file *did* work, it didn't tackle the root of the problem.

In the code below, it appeared that there was a timing delay with `getRandomInt()`, to where IE11 was too slow. The issue was resolved by "slowing down" the code with two `console.logs.`

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }

async function loadCommunityArticle(issueID) {
    axios.get(`${_something}/news/_api/lists/GetByTitle('News')/Items?$select=ID,Created,OtherThings&orderby=ID desc&$top=50`, restHeaders)
        .then(resp => {
            let _data = resp.data.d.results;
            if(_data && _data.length > 0) {
                let rand = getRandomInt(0, _data.length - 1);
                    console.log(rand);
                let item = _data[rand];
                    console.log(item);
// other code
```

After making the changes, the request hasn't failed in IE since.